# can not perform form validation

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I tried performing form validation on a registration form in jsp using javascript. I am not able to do it.
The page, despite the fields being blank, is directed to next page on clicking the submit button. And strangely, the blank data is entered in the database(row is added with blank entries).

```
       <html>

       <head> 

     <script type="text/javascript">
     function ckh()
        {

        var fn=document.rform.fname.value;
        var ln=document.rform.lname.value;
        var lad=document.rform.laddr.value;
        var pad=document.rform.paddr.value;
        var mo=document.rform.mno.value;
        var em=document.rform.email.value;
        var pd=document.rform.pwd.value;
        var a=isNAN(mo);

        var msg="";

        if(fn.length==0)
        {
            msg=msg+"First Name can not be blank! ";

        }

    if(ln.length==0)
    {
        msg=msg+"Last Name can not be blank! ";

    }
    if(lad.length==0)
    {
        msg=msg+"Address can not be blank! ";

    }
    if(pad.length==0)
    {
        msg=msg+"City Name can not be blank! ";
    }



    if(mo.length==0)
    {
        msg=msg+"Please enter mobile number! ";

    }

    if(em.length==0)
    {
        msg=msg+"Enter Email ID! ";

    }

    if(pd.length==0)
    {
        msg=msg+"Password can not be blank! ";

    }

    if(a)
    {
        msg=msg+"Please enter valid phone number! ";

    }

    if(msg.length==0)
    {
    rform.submit();
    }
    else
    {
        alert(msg);
        return false;

    }
     }

  </script>

    <title>Shop Online</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
   <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   </head>

   <body background="images/background3.jpg">
   <center>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="logo"> Shop<strong>Online</strong></div>
   <div class="menu">
   <ul class="solidblockmenu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="login.jsp">LOGIN</a></li>
    <li><a href="register.jsp">REGISTER</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a></li>

  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <% Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
       Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection  ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","manhattan");
       PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select *from uinfo");
       ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
       int n=0;
       while(rs.next())
       {
         n=rs.getInt("lid");

       }
       n++;

       //out.println(n);


       con.close();

    %>

    <form name="rform" action="register" method="post" onsubmit="return ckh()">
     <table border="0" cellspacing="11" cellpadding="11" align="center" bgcolor="skyblue">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4" align="center">
                        REGISTRATION FORM
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        First Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="fname">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Last Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="lname">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Address
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="laddr">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        City
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="paddr">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Mobile No
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="mno">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Email
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="email">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Login id
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label name="lid"><%=n %></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Password
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="pwd">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="New User">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did the same for login form and it worked there. In login form I have only two fields.......but I am not able to do in this one.

Comment: You get an error because you have misspelled `NaN`. Change `isNAN` to `isNaN` (little A).

Comment: Well it solves the issues partially........I am now getting the alert message which displays message about missing fields...but as soon I press OK...I am immediately directed to thanks page....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you have misspelled `NaN`; `NaN` is spelled with a little a. In your code you have `var a=isNAN(mo);` at line 16. Change it to `var a=isNaN(mo);`.

Comment: Well it solves the issues partially........I am now getting the alert message which displays message about missing fields...but as soon I press OK...I am directed to thanks page....

Comment: @IRON-MAN Have you edited your code in some other way?

Comment: @IRON-MAN Make sure you have `onsubmit="return ckh()"` and not `onsubmit="ckh()"`

Comment: thanx Afsa...........I changed onsubmit="return chk()" to onsubmit="chk()"  and forgot to change it back....!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
function ckh(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  //... do stuff here
}
```

is this working ? if no, try to log arguments in your function : you should get the event as the first argument, then try also onsubmit="chk()" without the return

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that solves your issue:

In Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

or

In Javascript:
Calling function as onclick="cancelFormSubmission()"

```
function cancelFormSubmission(e) {
    var evt = e ? e:window.event;
    if (evt.preventDefault){
       evt.preventDefault();
    }
    evt.returnValue = false;

    // Add your validation code from here
    ----
    ----
    ----
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code. You just need to include jquery script into your page.

Comment: why that dollar sign?

Comment: Yes, added solution in javascript too. Check it, I hope it will solve your issue.